# PIVOT First column to Headers

Tags: t-sql

I have a rather long procedure that creates a table variable that is ALWAYS 13 rows and there are always 19 columns. I know the names of every column and first variable of each row. The problem is that I don't know how to pivot the table for easy readout to a website. I have to build the html table row by row, but the clients are used to having the month abbreviation on the top.

Here's what the table looks like with a [SELECT * FROM @TEMP];

```
MonthName|Number_Screened|...|Tax_Credits_Earned|...|Year_To_Date_Tax_Credits_Earned
---------+---------------+---+------------------+---+-------------------------------
Jan      |159            |...|11030.26          |...|11030.26
Feb      |114            |...|6755.83           |...|17786.09
Mar      |107            |...|18250.73          |...|36036.82
Apr      |149            |...|11825.55          |...|47862.37
May      |117            |...|26149.78          |...|74012.15
Jun      |146            |...|11907.49          |...|85919.64
Jul      |104            |...|NULL              |...|85919.64
Aug      |NULL           |...|NULL              |...|85919.64
Sep      |NULL           |...|NULL              |...|85919.64
Oct      |NULL           |...|NULL              |...|85919.64
Nov      |NULL           |...|NULL              |...|85919.64
Dec      |NULL           |...|NULL              |...|85919.64
Total    |896            |...|85919.64          |...|85919.64
```

The months and Total will always show up and will always be in that order as the temporary table is constructed in that order, line by line with a loop.

This is what I want it to look like;

```
                               |Jan     |Feb     |Mar     |...|Total
-------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+---+--------
Number_Screened                |159     |114     |107     |...|896
...                            |...     |...     |...     |...|...
Tax_Credits_Earned             |11030.26|6755.83 |18250.73|...|85919.64 
...                            |...     |...     |...     |...|...
Year_To_Date_Tax_Credits_Earned|11030.26|17786.09|36036.82|...|85919.64
```

I've never successfully used pivot before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to UNPIVOT your data first, and then PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select A.MonthName 
              ,B.*
         From  @Temp A
         Cross Apply ( values (1,'Number_Screened'   ,[Number_Screened])
                             ,(2,'Tax_Credits_Earned',[Tax_Credits_Earned])
                             ,(3,'Year_To_Date_Tax_Credits_Earned',[Year_To_Date_Tax_Credits_Earned])
                     ) B(Seq,Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot (sum(Value) for MonthName in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec],[Total]) ) pvt
 Order By Seq
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to put the cross apply in order of the application?  When I add Docs_Outstanding after Number_Screened it appears before Number_Screened. How would I enforce the cross apply order without prefixing numbers?

Comment: @Kayot Sure, I added a SEQ to the CROSS APPLY